# What role has skin on translation for "Contact with the skin of the patient"

Tags: traducción

Being in a medical device context and reading a component it says

```
"Contact with the skin of the patient (hand)"
```

How would be the best way to translate it, and also How would you use skin here?

```
En contacto con la piel del paciente (mano).
```

or maybe

```
Está en contacto con la piel del paciente (mano).
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> En contacto con la piel del paciente (mano)

o

> En contacto con la piel de la mano del paciente

o

> En contacto con la mano del paciente.

Comment: the first one has something... Second and third are good options